# MongoDB return if field has more than one result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following collection

```
db.createCollection("BOOK", {TITLE : String, AUTHOR : String, ISBN : Number, 
PUBLISHER: { NAME : String, 
     DATE : Date, 
     CITY : String,
         ADDRESS: [{ STREET : String,
                CITY : String ,
                    ZIP : Number ,
                    STATE : String ,
                    COUNTRY : String }]},
AVAILABLE: Boolean,
PAGES : Number ,
LANGUAGE : String } )
```

With the data for a book with two publishers:

```
db.BOOK.insert({TITLE : 'Southern Lights', AUTHOR : 'Danielle Steel', ISBN : 303041974, 
PUBLISHER: { NAME : 'Random House', 
     DATE : new Date("Apr 23,2002"), 
     CITY : 'New York',
         ADDRESS: { STREET : ['1475 Broadway','375 Hudson Street'],
                CITY : 'New York' ,
                    ZIP : [10019 ,10014],
                    STATE : 'New York' ,
                    COUNTRY : 'US'   } },
AVAILABLE: 'Y',
PAGES : 2042 ,
LANGUAGE : 'English' } )

db.BOOK.insert({TITLE : 'Southern Lights', AUTHOR : 'Danielle Steel', ISBN : 303041974, 
PUBLISHER: { NAME : 'Penguin Publishers' , 
     DATE : new Date("Jan 19,1998"), 
     CITY : 'New York',
         ADDRESS: { STREET : '140 Broadway',
                CITY : 'New York' ,
                    ZIP : 10013,
                    STATE : 'New York' ,
                    COUNTRY : 'US'   } },
AVAILABLE: 'Y',
PAGES : 2042 ,
LANGUAGE : 'English' } )
```

If I wanted to retrieve all information on books that have multiple publishers (such as the result above), what query should I use? I know there is a query for greater than ($gt) but I am not sure how to go about using it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following aggregation framework pipeline:

```
db.BOOK.aggregate([
{
    $group: { _id: { TITLE : "$TITLE", AUTHOR : "$AUTHOR", ISBN : '$ISBN' }, publishers: { $addToSet: '$PUBLISHER'} }}
},
{
    $unwind:"$publishers"
},
{
    $group: { _id: "$_id", publisherCount: { $sum:1} }
},
{
    $match: {publisherCount: { $gte:2} }
}
]);
```

It treats ISBN as a unique identifier of a book, then builds a set of publishers for each book. Then counts then publishers for each book and returns only those books where the number of publishers is greater or equal to 2.

Comment: so this would return all information on all books with more than one publisher?

Comment: By all information you mean the book details? Also, are they bound to be the same for books with the same ISBN?

Comment: I have modified my example to return all fields

Comment: yes, all information as in all fields of book details. thank you!

Comment: Done, modified the example as requested. It may not be too efficient to group in such a way. You can consider simply returning ISBN numbers as I have shown originally and then making a simple find query to get the details.

Comment: so if i wanted it to be more efficient, i would just group by ISBN then db.book.find( ?? )

Comment: Yes indeed, that is what I meant

Comment: @salivad { 'ISBN' : "the_ISBN_number_gathered_with_code_I_provided" }. So first you do your group (keeping it as simple as you can, as it can be resource-intensive), and then get the details using results of that operation

Answer (score 0):

This requires an aggregate operation whereby you need to **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** the input documents (in this case all the documents in the collection) by the `ISBN` key, add an extra field within the group (using **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)**) that is a list which holds the
**[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)** document with each group and another field that denotes the count (using the accumulator **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)**).

The next pipeline using **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** should filter the result from the grouping on the `count` field.

---

Consider running the following aggregate pipeline to get the desired result:

```
db.BOOK.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$ISBN",
            "books": { "$push": "$$ROOT" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },    
])
```